# using srcset and size to switch images and different media querys

Tags: image, size, srcset

I am trying to switch a responsive image when it gets down to mobile, at the moment I'm using picturefill.js and also srcset and sizes to do the switching, however the images are not switching from the code used bellow.

```
<img srcset="/images/marketing/large.png 1190w, /images/marketing/mobile.png 320w"
 sizes="(min-width: 767px), (max-width: 768px)"
 alt="A rad wolf" 
 class="img-responsive" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sizes attribute is invalid. With the sizes attribute, you define the display width of your image element. And you can use media conditions to define different breakpoints. You are only using media conditions, but don't add a size.

Example:

`sizes="(min-width: 767px) 760px, 100vw"`

Which means if the viewport is larger than 767 the image is displayed at 760px otherwise it has the full viewport.

Additionally the first media condition that matches is taken, therefore you don't need to mix min-width and max-width. It is much easier to either use max-width or min-width.

`sizes="(min-width: 980px) 980px, 100vw"`

The same sizes described with max-width:

`sizes="(max-width: 980px) 100vw, 980px"`

You can also try to use [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes) which adds the sizes automatically for you.